# In Pyside6 (Or C++ Qt), how do I set a custom QML style at runtime?

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside, qtquick2

I want to use a custom style for my QML application. I have followed these instructions: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#creating-a-custom-style

I have a directory structure like this

```
MyApp/
├─ main.py
├─ QML/
│  ├─ Main.qml
├─ MyStyle/
│  ├─ qmldir
│  ├─ ToolTip.qml
```

I have created a style by creating a module (using a qmldir, and putting QML files inside it)

My `qmldir` contains

```
module MyStyle
ToolTip 3.0 ToolTip.qml
```

And `ToolTip.qml` contains

```
import QtQuick.Templates 2.0 as T
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

T.ToolTip {
    id: control
    text: qsTr("A descriptive tool tip of what the button does")

    contentItem: Text {
        text: control.text
        font: control.font
        color: "red"
    }

    background: Rectangle {
        border.color: "grey"
    }
}
```

I then tried to apply this in `main.py` (The API is very similar to the C++ one)

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
QQuickStyle.setStyle("MyStyle")
engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(f"{os.path.dirname(__file__)}/QML/Main.qml"))
app.exec()
```

But during `engine.load` I get the error:

```
file:///D:/MyApp/QML/Main.qml: module "MyStyle" is not installed `QQuickStyle.setStyle`
```

It is interesting that the error only happens once `engine.load` is reached. `QQuickStyle.setStyle` does not give an error (however, it also does not error even if nonsense is given).

I have tried adding:

```
engine.registerModule("MyStyle", os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/MyStyle")
```

And:

```
engine.setImportPathList([os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/MyStyle"])
```

But these also does not work.

How do I install my custom style so I can use it, just like I would use:

```
QQuickStyle.setStyle("Material")
```

Thanks

*edit*

If I add:

```
engine.addPluginPath(f"{os.path.dirname(__file__)}/MyStyle")
qmlRegisterModule("MyStyle", 1, 0)
```

Then I do not get the error, but my ToolTip style is still not applied.

Comment: Did you test if it works if you name the folder also MyStyle?

Comment: @iam_peter I have just tested that now, and it still does not work. Even with registerModule and setImportPathList

Comment: I have also tried "addPluginPath": https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlengine.html#addPluginPath

Answer (score 0):

Your directory is called `Style` could you test if it works when you rename it to match your style name `MyStyle`.

From the documentation you've shared:

> The style name must match the casing of the style directory; passing
> mystyle or MYSTYLE is not supported.

Comment: I have just tested it with this, and while this has probably solved some problems, it's not fully fixed it. I get the same error. I will edit the question with the new folder name, as that was certainly one issue, but not the issue I am stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of trial and error, I have found the answer:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
#THIS NEEDS TO BE THE PATH WITH THE MODULE DIR, NOT THE MODULE DIR ITSELF
engine.addImportPath(f"{os.path.dirname(__file__)}")    
#NOW YOU CAN ADD IT AS A STYLE
QQuickStyle.setStyle("MyStyle")
QQuickStyle.setFallbackStyle("Material")
url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(args.qml)
engine.load(url)
ret = app.exec()
```

Comment: This is written in the documentation. The files must be in a directory that is findable via the QML Import Path.
For example, if the path to MyStyle directory mentioned above was /home/user/MyApp/MyStyle, then /home/user/MyApp must be added to the QML import path.